# Extracting data from text file and import to Elasticsearch using Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I'm having a text file that I need to import into my Elasticsearch. My text file format is:

```
1            ARsv200711042           Allen                         Alane                         
2            ARsv200711042           Allen                         Arthur                        
3            ARsv200711042           Allen                         Bernice                       
4            ARsv200711042           Allen                         Betty                         
5            ARsv200711042           Allen                         Brittany                      
6            ARsv200711042           Allen                         Bruce                         
7            ARsv200711042           Allen                         Carolyn                       
8            ARsv200711042           Allen                         Carolyn                       
9            ARsv200711042           Allen                         Chadderick                    
10           ARsv200711042           Allen                         Darlene
```

I need to capture the data concerning the position; for example, the first column is eMID, which is from 1st position to 13th position, I've StateSource is at position 14-15, CodeProducts is at position 16-17, and so on.

So I made Logstash configuration something like this:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "D:/sample/sample 500.txt"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { 
            "message" => [
                "(?<eMID>.{0,13})(?<StateSource>.{0,2})(?<CodeProducts>.{0,2})(?<AcquiredDate>.{0,8})(?<Uses>.{0,2})(?<Prefix>.{0,10})(?<LName>.{0,30})(?<FName>.{0,30})"
            ]
        }
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "sample-data"
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
}
```

I was able to import the data successfully. I've the following questions:

- How to format the date field, for eg. I've acquired date in format `20071104` which needs to be transformed into date format, which elasticsearch can analyze
- Since we are taking positions, there are possibilities that a lot of trailing whitespaces can appear, how to trim those whitespaces.
- In some cases a few of the columns for eg. `Firstname/FName` or `Lastname/LName` may contain special characters such as `+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \` etc, how can I also match those with regex and insert into elasticsearch.

Comment: lets tackle your first question. so you have this date `20071104` and you want this to be transformed to what format? like `yyyy-mm-dd` or something else?

Comment: @JBone yes `yyyy-mm-dd` will do

Comment: check out the below answer that should answer your first two questions of the three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so one way is to split `20071104` into four parts `\d{4}` and assign this to y, and next two digits `\d{2}` to m and remaining two digits `\d{2}` to d and frame a date object

or second way is to create a date from the string and using that object to reformat like in this example I did, assuming AcquiredDate is 20071104

```
filter {
     
      ruby {
           code => '
                 date = Date.strptime(event.get("AcquiredDate"), "%Y%m%d")
                 event.set("new_time", date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
           '
      }
      mutate {
         remove_field =>
                       ["host","@timestamp","sequence","message","@version"]
      }
 }
```

gives you

```
{
    "AcquiredDate" => "20071104",
    "new_time" => "2007-11-04"
}
```

to answer your second part

use something like this

```
mutate { 
  strip => ["field1withwhitespace", "field2withwhitespace"] 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the dates are dynamic, under the field name AcquiredDate.

Comment: yep I understand that. you should use `date = Date.strptime(event.get("AcquiredDate"), "%Y%m%d")`

Comment: I just showed the logic. You will have to adjust the `mutate {remove_field => ` stuff too.

Comment: So you mean `mutate {
            add_field => {"old_time" => "20071104"}
      }` will be `mutate {
            add_field => {"old_time" => "AcquiredDate"}
      }`

Comment: no ..remove all the fields that you don't want to send them to Elasticsearch.

Comment: basically this block ..in here, remove all the fields that are specific to your system and you dont like to capture them into elasticsearch `mutate {
         remove_field =>
                       ["host","@timestamp","sequence","message","@version"]
      }`

Comment: I'm talking about the first code block `old_time`

Comment: ha I see. you can totally delete that block...I updated the answer again..please check